# How equate capacitor's voltage for mixed series paralell RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks

I need to find the voltage's equation across the capacitor in the schematic below using differential equations.

My professor said that it's a simple matter of finding the natural and step responses and adding the results together, but I cannot see how this problem can be that easy.

There is no need to solve the differential equation, just a demonstration on how to get it will be accepted as an answer.

**Important:** Vg is actually a ***Square Wave***, I could not find the symbol in the schematic provided.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxTDnc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is your attempt doing circuit analysis? Forgot about the square wave first, if you can do circuit analysis to find the capacitor voltage, then whatever input voltage will be easily follows off. If you don't need to use differential equation, voltage divider using Laplace representation \$V_{cap}(s) = \frac{(R+sL) // (1/sC)}{ ((R+sL) // (1/sC)) + Rg} \cdot V_g(s)\$ find the laplace representation of square wave input signal and then inverse Laplace it, you'll get the time-domain solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Although the Laplace transform could be a simple solution my course demands that I should solve this problem by means of differential equations. Laplace is a topic that is not requirement to this course and it wouldn't be accepted in an exam as resolution method, for example.

Comment: Okay, so what is your attempt doing circuit analysis? KVL KCL? Nodal? Mesh?

Comment: My first and foolish attempt was to perform a source transformation to a current source in parallel with Rg and then I used the node voltage method. The result was an over-complicated equation.

Comment: I just found the method that my professor was probably trying to explain. In the page 339, example 8.9, of this [book](http://omega.altervista.org/extra/Fundamentals%20of%20Electric%20Circuits%20(Alexander%20and%20Sadiku),%204th%20Edition.pdf). It seems very clear to me how this should work in my circuit. Right now is very late where I live, so tomorrow I will try this method and post the result here.

Comment: Any progress on it?